# ISO8601 with milliseconds in json using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, datetime-format, iso8601

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat;

objectMapper.setDateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat());
```

Nice but this ignores milliseconds, how can I get them in the dates without using the non-thread-safe `SimpleDateFormatter`?

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601DateFormat.java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ISO8601DateFormat.format` calls `ISO8601Utils.format(date)`, which in turn calls [`format(date, false, TIMEZONE_Z)`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/ISO8601Utils.java#L38) - the `false` parameter tells jackson to don't include the milliseconds.

There seems to be no way to configure this class nor set any parameter, but fortunately it can be extended:

```
public class ISO8601WithMillisFormat extends ISO8601DateFormat {
    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
        String value = ISO8601Utils.format(date, true); // "true" to include milliseconds
        toAppendTo.append(value);
        return toAppendTo;
    }
}
```

Then we can use this new class in the object mapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ISO8601DateFormat dateFormat = new ISO8601WithMillisFormat();
objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
```

I've made a test with `new Date()` and the result was `2017-07-24T12:14:26.817Z` (with the milliseconds).